# undefined reference to `sctp_get_no_strms'

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

I have a link error when trying to use `sctp_get_no_strms` function. I am running Slackware 14.1 and have lksctp-tools installed.

```
# ls /var/log/packages | grep sctp
lksctp-tools-1.0.16-x86_64-1_SBo
```

However libsctp symbol list does not include this function.

```
# nm -D /usr/lib64/libsctp.so | grep sctp_get
0000000000001100 T sctp_getaddrlen
00000000000010e0 T sctp_getladdrs
00000000000010c0 T sctp_getpaddrs
```

Is `sctp_get_no_strms` not supported by lksctp-tools?

The compilation command is as follows:

```
gcc -o srv sctpserv01.o sctp_wrapper.o -L../lib -lsock -lsctp
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  If the symbol isn't in the library, there are three main possibilities. (1) The version of the library you have doesn't have it, but other (probably newer) versions of the library do, or (2) the 'function' is normally defined as a macro in a header that calls onto other functions instead, or (3) the library doesn't know what the function is so all calls to it are immaterial.  (2) is less likely than (1); at the moment, I'd rate (3) as most probable.

Comment: You should go and consult the documentation for the library — it should be easy enough to find (Google searching for 'lksctp-tools source code' gets to [Linux Kernel SCTP Tools](http://lksctp.sourceforge.net/) quite quickly.  The documentation references aren't immediately inspiring, but they are the correct place to start.  Failing that, download the source and see if you can find the function.  If not, consult where you got the information about `sctp_get_no_strms()` function and see what it has to say about it.  1.0.16 is the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that function is defined in the source code available for the book. Confusingly it is not declared in the header file `unp.h`. It is defined in `sctp/sctp_getnostrms.c`.

Answer (score 0):

When using functions from a library, the appropriate header file needs to be #include'd — for example `#include "unp.h"` since the function `sctp_get_no_strms()` is described in Stevens [Unix Network Programming, Volume 1: The Sockets API, 3rd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) and is specific to that book.

Note that `unp.h` is not a standard system header, which is why I used `"unp.h"` rather than `<unp.h>` (with angle brackets around the header file name).

Comment: A Google search for 'sctp_get_no_strms' does show that the function is mentioned/described in [Unix Network Programming](http://www.amazon.com/Unix-Network-Programming-Volume-Networking/dp/0131411551) -- see [Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&pg=PA290&lpg=PA290&dq=sctp_get_no_strms&source=bl&ots=Ks3zTlclSm&sig=Hffwd2iyS7I4UARytkPtj06DL-g&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kpdnVZTWE4isyASX9IPgDA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=sctp_get_no_strms&f=false).  Hence `unp.h` is not necessarily out of order (that is a header used in that book).  But the absence of explanation is a problem!

Comment: However, the header helps the compilation (to object file) phase; the problem appears to be in the linking phase.  The source for the function needs to be found and compiled and linked with the program.  You may be able to get it from the book's web site: http://www.unpbook.com/src.html.  I've not validated that hypothesis.

Comment: It turns out that function is defined in the source code available for the book. Confusingly it is not declared in the header file `unp.h`. It is defined in `sctp/sctp_getnostrms.c`.

Comment: Reference: UNIX Network Programming, Volume 1 Third Edition page 290 - W. Richard Stevens, Bill Fenner, Andrew M. Rudoff

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

You'd like to use this command to recompile:

```
gcc -I../lib -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -Wall -g -c sctp_getnostrm.c ../libunp.a -lpthread -L/usr/local/v6/lib -lm -lsctp
```

After that, you'll get `sctp_getnostrm.o` in the directory `sctp`.

Finally, recompile and link by this:

```
gcc -I../lib -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -Wall -g -o sctpserv01 sctpserv01.o sctp_wrapper.o sctp_getnostrm.o sctp_addr_to_associd.o ../libunp.a -lpthread -L/usr/local/v6/lib -lm -lsctp
```